# Create newline with awk Command?

Tags: unix, geektool

Im trying to edit a script in geek tool (mac app for desktop widgets), could someone help me make this statement only print out 10 or so words per line?

```
curl -s www.brainyquote.com/quotes_of_the_day.html | egrep '(div class="bqQuoteLink")|    (ahref)' | sed -n '19p; 20p;' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'\
```

Just now everything is printed out on one big line.

I think i could use the awk command, although I am unsure how to do so on this output.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running it through:

```
| fold -s
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the end of your command

```
 | awk '{ print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 }'
```

That should only print the first nine words per line, assuming they're space-delimited.